# Map a subclass of a common element in relational database

Tags: sql

I need to map a relation between a city council and its area of influence. Each city has one area of influence and one subarea. Each influence area has several subareas. For example,

```
table city
 - influence_area: Foreign key to influence_area table
 - influence_subarea: Foreign key to influence_subarea table

table influence_area:
 - name

table influence_suberea
 - name
 - influence_area: Foreign key to influence_area table
```

So clearly there is a redundancy in the definition. Is it good practice to reference only the subarea in the city table? What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Why does city have a foreign key to SubArea (ie. Each city has one special SubArea) ?

Comment: Also, can one InfluenceArea belong to more than one city ?  ... Or to no cities?

Comment: Fixed the question. One influence area may have several cities. A city may have only one area and one subarea. One influence area may have several subareas.

Comment: I added a foreign key to sub_area to show the problem with my modeling.

Comment: Just found out that this problem is already been investigated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

In your model, sub area is belonging to area AND city, this is wrong.

The best way is:
- sub area is belonging only to area
- area is belonging only to city

in this way:

```
table city
 - influence_area: Foreign key to influence_area table
 - influence_subarea: Foreign key to influence_area table

table influence_area:
 - name

table influence_suberea
 - name
 - influence_area: Foreign key to influence_area table
```

all sub-area are belongning to city.influence_area and only 1 to city.influence_subarea

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: solution is: influence_subarea: Foreign key to influence_area table and not influence_subarea

Comment: Yeah, but in this case I have to keep two foreign tables in city and I was trying to avoid that, as if the city belongs to a subarea I already know its area.

Comment: so, why not remove city.influence_subarea and let first sub-area belongs to city.influence_area ?    city <--- area <--- sub_area